# Neo4j eager/lazy loading with Spring data

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data

I'm investigating Neo4j and have a question with regards to object eager/lazy loading. Lets say I have class Trolley with has `Set<Item>` (with getters/setters). If I do the following:

```
Trolley t = new Trolley(...); // create empty trolley
t.addItem(f);  // add one item to the trolley
t.persist(); // persist the object
```

I then later find the trolley based on the nodeId:

```
repo.findOne(xxx); // returns the trolley successfully
```

When I do something like:

```
trolley.getItems().size()
```

this is empty. I guess this is the intended behaviour. Is there any mechanism similar to JPA where is the session/tx is open to load the collection dynamically.

Code:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Trolley
{
    @Indexed
    private String name;

    @RelatedTo
    private Set<Item> items;

    public Trolley(){}

    public Trolley(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addItem(Item item)
    {
        this.items.add(item);
    }

    public Set<Item> getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }

}

@NodeEntity
public class Item
{
    private String name;

    public Item(){}

    public Item(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

@Test
public void trolleyWithItemPersist()
{
    Trolley trolley = new Trolley("trolley1").persist();

    // Persisting - however I would've expected a cascade to
    // occur when adding to the collection.
    Item item =  new Item("item1").persist();

    // now add to the trolley
    trolley.addItem(item);

    // persist
    trolley.persist();

    // Now use repo to get trolley
    Trolley loadedTrolley = trolleyRepository.findOne(trolley.getNodeId());

    // should have one item
    assertEquals(1, loadedTrolley.getItems().size());

}
```

Comment: Is f also a NodeEntity? It might be needed that you persist that one first. Normally it should work by cascading forward but that might be a corner-case.

Can you show the class definitions of Trolley and "f"?

Thanks

Comment: f is indeed an NodeEntity. I've tried to persist that first, but the net result is the same. i.e. f.persist() then adding to the collection. I guess I could try @RelationshipEntity? I'll paste the definitions and a simple test.

Comment: Hi Michael, I think you were right, fix was to persist first then add to the collection. I expected a cascade to occur to recognize that the element added has the appropriate meta-data to show that it also is a node. Working test is shown above, not doing the persist on Item item =  new Item("item1").persist(); will cause the test to fail.

Comment: Btw Thanks Michael, just saw you name in the API :)

Comment: Thanks :). Btw. it should cascade, you're right that is on our plans. The problem is that cascading / fetching is a pandora's box, so we want to make sure to provide a good set of solutions for that. (Especially on how to control the cascade/fetch behavior). If you have any feedback on that feel free to share it.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, in Spring Data Jpa, to populate an lazy loaded field you need to annotate the method which call the `findOne(xxx)` with

```
@Transactional
```

from `(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)`

Maybe it works also with `neo4j`...

I'm not really an skilled developper on Spring Data but this is the only way I know to retrieve lazy loaded fields. If someone has a better solution, feel free to write it!